# Understanding wait() and signal()

Tags: c, signals, deadlock, wait

I have 2 processes P1 and P2 that share 3 semaphores (s1, s2, s3) each with an initial value of 1 and also 3 variables (x, y, z)

```
P1:                  P2:
wait(s1);            wait(s2);  
x = x + 1;           y = y * 2;
wait(s2);            wait(s3);
y = y - x;           z = z - y;
wait(s3);            signal(s2);
z = x + 2 * y - z;   wait(s1);
signal(s3);          x = x + 2;
signal(s2);          signal(s1);
signal(s1);          signal(s3);
```

If I were to run them concurrently on a computer with a single CPU, is it possible for P1 and P2 to get into a deadlock?

How I look at it is that as soon as they start running, they both wait() which causes them to sit until something signals() them. Since nothing else is running, then aren't they both in deadlock? I feel I am missing some critically simple knowledge that is hindering my understanding. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three semaphores in your example are initialized with 1, therefore the won't block at the first line of each process.

Now consider this sample run:

- P2 runs until the wait(s1), just before that statement gets executed. At this point, semaphores s2 and s1 have a count of 1 and s3 a count of 0.
- Now P1 executes until wait(s3) that it cannot acquire because its value is 0, but to get there it has taken ownership of s1 and s2
- Now P2 resumes execution but gets instantly blocked waiting for s1

At that point both processes are in deadlock.

Comment: That makes sense! But my question then is why can P2 run until wait(s1). Since P1 and P2 are running concurrently, doesn't that meant that they run "line for line" with each other?

Comment: @Kyle: In a scenario with only one CPU the OS will bring the illusion of concurrency by alternating CPU cycles to the running processes. Therefore any process can be momentaneously blocked to give the CPU to another process at *any* time, and so on and so forth. So my sample execution is valid and leads to deadlock

Comment: I took some time to look at it again, and running it line for line IS what caused this to happen just as your example shows. I was a tad too hasty.

Comment: Another side question still relating to this then: could there be a possible deadlock if P1:y=y-x and P2:z=z-y were to try and run at the  same time? 
They would both be trying to access the same variables at the same time and cause a deadlock correct?

Comment: @Kyle: no, that would just the result of those statements a bit unpredictable. Assignments are not blocking statements.

Answer (score 0):

When P2 wait(s1), s1 must be in P1's hand, so P2 cannot go on to signal(S3), then P1 wait(s3) forever. This is the deadlock.

Comment: If that is the case, then wouldnt the deadlock occur earlier? P1:wait(s1) takes s1. P2:wait(s2) takes s2. Then P1:wait(s2) wants to take s2, but P2 has already taken it. Is that correct logic?

Comment: No. Since P1 is waiting(s2), P2 can go on execution to signal(s2).

Comment: This makes sense now thanks to the further explanation by @gusbro. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Two kinds of deadlock

**1) Signals (consumable resources)**

– Each task waiting for signal from another
– Can't back out

**2) Units (reusable resources)**

- Each task waiting for another to release a resource unit.Can back out
  by aborting tasks until enough resources available to free others.

**Signal Deadlock**

[image: Fig:Signal Deadlock]

Initially, semaphores a and b are both 1.
Deadlock

```
 if P1 and P2 complete their
first wait’s simultaneously before
attempting their second wait’s
```

.

**May not be easy to test for signal deadlocks:**

[image: not be easy to test]

Deadlock may result

```
 if P1 calls T(a,b) and
P2 calls T(b,a) at the same time.
```

Comment: This helps to clarify in general. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

No, because they are different processes. I think you are talking about a Mutex right?

Comment: I wonder if the person who marked this question does know the difference between a Mutex and a Semaphore. How do you share semaphores in different processes??

Comment: When you said processes, are you talking about different threads in the same execution context?

Comment: No. I meant Unix/Linux process.

Comment: Ok, I was relating this to .net which has the same sematics.

"Generally you only use a Mutex across processes, e.g. if you have a resource that multiple applications must share, or if you want to build a single-instanced app (i.e. only allow 1 copy to be running at one time).

A semaphore allows you to limit access to a specific number of simultaneous threads, so that you could have, for example, a maximum of two threads executing a specific code path at a time."

That´s why I asked about the Mutex, although you can have a named OS semaphore as well.